# Ajax security issues and possible attacks

Tags: jquery, ajax, security

The project I am working on, uses AJAX calls for every link on the page, more specifically, jQuery AJAX calls, also, every form submitted, besides logging in, is submitted through AJAX, and there is a bit of json, and xml, in the mix, My question is, what are the security risks of this? All of the server side code is PHP, and everything is properly escaped.

Comment: The data is being sent using GET or POST?

Comment: how do you check if an ajax request came from an authenticated user? (and is not spoofed)

Comment: @Tadeck: does it matter?

Comment: using an two different encrypted  keys that change with each request.

Comment: @zerkms A little. I mean CSRF is pretty easy when you do not have referer checks, checks for AJAX-specific headers and GET methods used for making AJAX calls. It just comes to sending you to the prepared URL - you do not even have to prepare POST calls. What do you think?

Comment: @Tadeck: `csrf` protection (not referrer, but random string-based)  is necessary for all requests, get/post/put/etc, peformed by normal post, by clicking a link, by ajax request, ...

Comment: @zerkms Correct. But it is really easy to perform such attack even by giving bit.ly link, when you use GET, use no referer checking and do not check for AJAX header. That is what I had in mind. But yes, you should use tokens etc. to fight against CSRF.

Comment: Detailed answer http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/ajax/

Comment: Also you can find some guidelines on OWASP website : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_AJAX_Security_Guidelines

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing specific in AJAX. It is just a request performed by your browser. It is just general HTTP request and should be secured as any other HTTP request, regardless its XHR nature.

Comment: AJAX requests carry credentials and thus opening up services to Ajax potentially opens them up to XSRF as well.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: uhm, what?! Ajax requests don't more vulnerable than "normal" requests, just because **it is the same things**. Btw, thanks for downvote. Waiting for your proofs.

Comment: @zerkms, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project lists  XSRF as number 5.  The OP's environment is PHP on the server, JS on the client submitting all data via Ajax.  The OP stipulates that they properly escape which prevents the client from being subverted.  What does that leave?  The server authority being abused.  Hence, they are still vulnerable to XSS, until/unless the server requires XSRF tokens and all authority bearing AJAX calls provide them.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I know what CSRF does mean. But ajax doesn't do application more vulnerable. Even non-ajax requests are csrf-vulnerability-proned. " OP stipulates that they properly escape" --- who said it to you? All requests should be processed in the same way, ajax and non-ajax. Because they don't have attack surface. If you cannot implement ajax-methods securely (this means **in the same way as other methods**) - it is your problems. And where did I say that we don't need to pass CSRF-tokens in all requests? Point me please?

Comment: @Mike Samuel: Btw, can you prove your words? If I give you a link with ajax-requests implemented in the same way as general requests - can you exploit any vulnerability? Or you're just the guy who can nothing but give references to the pages you cannot even understand?

Comment: @Mike I think what @zerkms was trying to say is a XHR is no less secure than any other request; they all need to be handled appropriately.

Comment: @Mike Samuel You have to sign every "update" http request with csrf token. Doesn't matter if it's ajax or non-ajax one. @zerkms you don't need to sign all requests - output is protected by same-origin-policy.

Comment: @alex, @Kamil, I don't think we disagree on any substantial point.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: well you did not answer. Can you prove your words if I provide any ajax endpoint that is secured as any non-ajax one? Do you enough competent to prove your words or you've already failed?

Comment: @zerkms.  Could you please clarify "It is just a request performed by your browser. Like the request of the page by typing its url in address bar and pressing enter."  Obviously an ajax request is not like typing a URL in the address bar.  An XHR request can carry headers that would not be sent with a request from a URL typed in the address bar.  An XHR request can have a method other than GET unlike a request initiated from the URL bar.  An XHR request can have a single arbitrary body also unlike a request initiated from the URL bar.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I meant that XHR is a general http-request and it should be processed on the server-side regardless its XHR nature. If request performs any action - it should be signed with some token, doesn't metter who and how sent it.

Comment: @zerkms.  I think we agree on substance then.  I raise XSRF because it is the single greatest overlooked security exploit I see people make when designing APIs to expose to AJAX clients which is why I call it out.  You are correct though that XSRF is also a matter for static web apps.  If you wouldn't mind updating your question to correct the part about equivalence to URL bar I will be happy to remove the downvote.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I gave that analogy because of the OP is not competent enough, so tried to explain it as simple as possible :-S Sorry.

Comment: @zerkms.  No problem.  Thanks for engaging in comments.

Comment: @zerkms, I remembered one AJAX specific attack vector, a kind of XSSI.  Mostly of historical interest though so I don't think it should be construed as invalidating your response.  See the other answer to this question for details.

Answer (score 2):

It was widely thought that it was unnecessary to use XSRF tokens to guard services that exposed only data via GET and that authorized the user via cookies.

This was not true.  These used to have an AJAX specific XSSI vulnerability when the output was a JSON array.

Consider a service `/getfriends` that returns data like `[ { "name": "Alice" }, { "name": "Bob" } ]`.

An attacking page could do

```
 <script>
   var stolenData;
   var RealArray = Array;
   Array = function () {
     return stolenData = new RealArray();
   };
 </script>
 <script src="https://naivedomain.com/getfriends" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the second `<script>` tag loaded the JSON across domain with the user's cookies
and because of a quirk in EcmaScript 3 (fixed in EcmaScript 5.0 and modern ES 3 interpreters) the page could read the stolen data because the JavaScript parser invoked the overridden `Array` constructor when parsing `[...]` in the JSON response.

Protecting these services via XSRF tokens in addition to normal cookie-based approaches solved the problem as does disallowing GET, authorizing via custom headers, and including a parse breaker.  Parse breakers work by making the response invalid JSON, e.g. returning `throw 0; [{ "name": "Alice" }, { "name": "Bob" }]` so an XHR client can strip off the `throw 0;` prefix, but a client loading via `<script>` cannot.

Finally, since the JavaScript parser parses a loaded script as a program, this only affected services that returned JSON arrays.  A `/getfriend` service that returned `{ "names": ["Alice", "Bob"] }` would not be vulnerable since that content is not a valid program -- it is parsed as a block with an invalid label.  But invalid JSON like `{ names: [ "Alice", "Bob" ] }` is vulnerable since that is a valid program.

Comment: Oh, cool, never knew that and even don't believe it would work :-S

Comment: @zerkms, The spec language that allowed this was in section 11.1.4 Array Initialiser which read "The production ArrayLiteral : [ Elisionopt
] is evaluated as follows:
1. Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array()`" but that was changed in EcmaScript 5 to read "Let array be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression `new Array()` where `Array` is the standard built-in constructor with that name."

Comment: @zerkms, see http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx for a better writeup.

Comment: yep, and to protect from that vulnerability google and facebook put the infinite loop in the begin of response, iirc.

Comment: @zerkms Hi friend, would you please explain a little about your last comment?

Comment: @sforsandeep, Instead of `throw 0; [...]`, some JSON responses had `while (1); [...]` to prevent control from ever reaching the object constructor.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks! But I didnt get that completely... If you dont mind, would you please share a little simple explanation??

Comment: @sforsandeep, To prevent `["secret"]` from leaking information as described above, you could do `while (1); ["secret"]` which works because the parser enters the loop and never reaches the place where it would call the attacker-supplied version of `new Array()`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel.. "while (1); [...]" how can I cut off the "while (1);"? Something like response.replace("while (1);", "");?

Comment: @random425, no.  You only want to replace the first, not legit occurrences as in `do ... while(1);` so maybe `response.replace(/^while \(1\);/, "")`

Comment: Thks a lot @MikeSamuel!

Answer (score -1):

Ajax violates security rules regarding percent escaping of reserved characters in POST data. Pure and simple, this allows direct injection of hostile code into SQL schemas, which can be things such as PHP code for later retrieval and execution on the host. Until AJAX begins escaping all reserved GET and POST characters, as normal browsers do with forms, it is not to be trusted without complete scanning on every communication for hostile code segments.